# Backspace only works once?

Tags: c#, substring

I've got a custom TextBox-like control. I'm trying to handle backspaces with this:

```
    private void PerformBackspace() {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Got a backspace. Text is currently \"{0}\".", (object)this.Text);
        string newText = this.Text.Substring(0, this.Text.Length - 1);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Changing text to \"{0}\".", (object)newText);
        this.Text = newText;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Text is now \"{0}\".", (object)this.Text);
    }
```

In `OnKeyDown` I call this method, and it works, but only for one character. Backspacing twice in a row does not work, you have to type at least one character between backspaces for some reason. Now is `Substring` just not working??? This is the output I get when I backspace twice:

> Got a backspace. Text is currently "My
>   textbox.".
> Changing text to "My
>   textbox".
> Text is now "My textbox".
>   Got a backspace. Text is currently "My
>   textbox".
> Changing text to "My
>   textbox".
> Text is now "My textbox".

This is quite possibly the strangest issue I have ever seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the `'\b'` character was getting appended to my text after pressing the backspace key.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling it from the OnKeyUp() event.

Comment: Why should this fix the problem?

Comment: That probably would have made me see it (see comment to original), thanks anyways. +1 @Cody Gray: It shouldn't.